# Java Future object with Runnable interface

Tags: java, logging, future

I have to do an assignment where I have to implement a background thread logger for a web service, for the logger we got some skeleton code where we have a run method and a method that returns a future object. For logging of activities we have to implement write ahead logging, I managed to start a new thread for the logger and I send it the command to log something when I execute an insert/update command in the web service (the web service implements a key to values map), but I can`t manage to make the main thread wait for the logging thread to finish logging. Does anybody have any suggestions? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
public class IndexImpl implements Index<KeyImpl,ValueListImpl>
{
    private Thread log_thread;
    private MyLogger log;

    /*
     * in out pair, the long refers to the initial memory address that our data
     * has been saved too, and the integer refers to the length of the data in the file 
     */

    private HashMap<KeyImpl,Pair<Long,Integer>> m;
    private long endAddr;

    public IndexImpl()
    {
        valSer = new ValueSerializerImpl();
        endAddr = 0;
        m = new HashMap<KeyImpl,Pair<Long,Integer>>();
        this.log= new MyLogger();
        this.log_thread= new Thread(log);
        log_thread.start();
    }

    public void insert(KeyImpl k, ValueListImpl v) throws KeyAlreadyPresentException, IOException {
        locker.WriteLock(k);
        try {
            if (m.containsKey(k)) {
                throw new KeyAlreadyPresentException(k);
            }
            else {
            //LOGGING
                Object[] array = new Object[3]; // Key, Old Value List, New Value List
                array[0]= k.toString(); //Key
                array[1]= null; // Old value list
                array[2]= v; // New value list

            LogRecord l = new LogRecord(MyKeyValueBaseLog.class, "insert", array);
            FutureLog<LogRecord> future = (FutureLog<LogRecord>) log.logRequest(l);
            System.out.println("Inserting a new key " + k.getKey());
            future.get();

            long tempEndAddr;
            byte[] temp = valSer.toByteArray(v);
            //we are using the ReentrantReadWriteLock implementation found in java
            write.lock();
            try{
                tempEndAddr = endAddr;

                endAddr += temp.length;
            }
            finally{
                write.unlock();
            }

            store.write(tempEndAddr, temp);
            m.put(k, new Pair<Long, Integer>(tempEndAddr,temp.length));

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    finally
    {
        locker.WriteUnlock(k);
    }
}
```

And the code for the logger is :

```
public class MyLogger implements Logger {

private ArrayList<LogRecord> log = new ArrayList<LogRecord>(100);


public MyLogger()
{

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("This is the logger thread! " + Thread.currentThread());
}

@Override
public Future<?> logRequest(LogRecord record) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.log.add(record);
    System.out.println("Record added to log! operation: " + record.getMethodName() );
    FutureLog<LogRecord> future = new FutureLog();
    return future;

}
```

}

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService to do this as it will simplify most of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logger thread is started and *will exit immediately*

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("This is the logger thread! " + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Instead, you need to loop in this method, writing log records as they come in. I would perhaps suggest reading from a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), and the method logRequest() should add log records to this queue. That way your `run()` method will just wait on the queue (using the [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) method provided by the queue) and write out each record as it takes it off the queue.

You'll need to be able to stop this, and perhaps [interrupting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) the thread is a solution here.

All of the above is simply one implementation choice. The fundamental problem you have is that your thread starts/stops almost instantaneously.

Comment: I just want to add that the OP is using the Future incorrectly, too.

Comment: ok. I implemented a blockingqueue in mylogger but I still can`t make the main thread wait till the logger is done before continuing operations. How should I implement Future?

Comment: Don't you have an impleentation already? `FutureLog`? You just have to create it and return it immediatly in `logRequest`. But keep the reference , because as soon as the thread is done with the work, it has to deliver the result to that future. On the client side, you call `get` on the returned Future. That blocks until the result is ready.

Comment: Yes.I think I`m doing what you`re saying. But it blocks the thread  when I use get after the first logging and those not unlock it. I do this in the logRequest method : {FutureLog<LogRecord> future = new FutureLog<LogRecord>(); try {
   this.queue.enqueue(record);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return future; }